# sqlite query for the best selling album in each genre

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, join, group-by

I am using the basic chinook database, but i can't figure out how to write a SQLite query to create a view called BestSeller for the bestselling album in each genre with sales (based on the quantity of tracks sold, named as Sales) with the columns: Genre, Album, Artist, Sales.

The schema for the album table:

```
 [Title] NVARCHAR(160)  NOT NULL,
 [ArtistId] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY ([ArtistId]) REFERENCES "artists" ([ArtistId])
```

artists table :

```
[ArtistId] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
[Name] NVARCHAR(120)
```

tracks table schema:

```
 [TrackId] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(200)  NOT NULL,
    [AlbumId] INTEGER,
    [MediaTypeId] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    [GenreId] INTEGER,
    [Composer] NVARCHAR(220),
    [Milliseconds] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    [Bytes] INTEGER,
    [UnitPrice] NUMERIC(10,2)  NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ([AlbumId]) REFERENCES "albums" ([AlbumId])
                ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY ([GenreId]) REFERENCES "genres" ([GenreId])
                ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY ([MediaTypeId]) REFERENCES "media_types" ([MediaTypeId])
                ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

table invoice_items:

```
    [InvoiceLineId] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceId] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    [TrackId] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    [UnitPrice] NUMERIC(10,2)  NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ([InvoiceId]) REFERENCES "invoices" ([InvoiceId])
                ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY ([TrackId]) REFERENCES "tracks" ([TrackId])
                ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

I have all these other tables as well.

```
albums          employees       invoices        playlists
artists         genres          media_types     tracks
customers       invoice_items   playlist_track
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the relevant tables and group by genre and album to get the quantity of tracks sold of each album.
Then use `FIRST_VALUE()` and `MAX()` window functions to get the album with the most sales in each genre and the the number of sales:

```
CREATE VIEW BestSeller AS
SELECT DISTINCT 
       g.Name Genre, 
       FIRST_VALUE(a.Title) OVER (PARTITION BY g.GenreId ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) Album, 
       FIRST_VALUE(r.Name) OVER (PARTITION BY g.GenreId ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) Artist, 
       MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY g.GenreId) Sales
FROM genres g
INNER JOIN tracks t ON t.GenreId = g.GenreId
INNER JOIN albums a ON a.AlbumId = t.AlbumId
INNER JOIN artists r ON r.ArtistId = a.ArtistId
INNER JOIN invoice_items i ON i.TrackId = t.TrackId
GROUP BY g.GenreId, a.AlbumId;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pywMXJteuo1avGWUs5CWRo/0)